# How to Show Snackbar within ScaffoldMessenger as Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

I have a new use case for Snackbar. I was asked to make a program which reads articles from API and it will show Snackbar when it reaches the end of articles. I meant, all examples of using Snackbar always use a button in order to display it. How can I display Snackbar when I reach the end of articles?

This is my code:

```dart
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (state.hasReachedMax) {
          return const SnackbarPage(); //<= This one
        } else {
          if (index >= state.posts.length) {
            return const BottomLoader();
          } else {
            return PostListItem(post: state.posts[index]);
          }
        }
      },
      itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.posts.length : state.posts.length + 1,
      controller: _scrollController,
    );
```

- **snackbar.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class SnackbarPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const SnackbarPage({super.key});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ScaffoldMessenger(  //Error here
            child: SnackBar(
              content: const Text('Reach the end of posts'),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                onPressed: () {
                  //if action button is pressed
                },
                label: 'Close',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I got error: `Null check operator used on a null value`

It seems that `ScaffoldMessenger` cannot be used as a Widget as return.

References: [Snackbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html) [ScaffoldMessenger](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessenger-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the Scaffold.of method to access the Scaffold ancestor of your ListView.builder, and then call the showSnackBar method on the Scaffold to display the Snackbar.

Would something like this work?

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (state.hasReachedMax) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: const Text('Reach the end of posts'),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            onPressed: () {
              //if action button is pressed
            },
            label: 'Close',
          ),
        ),
      );
      return Container();
    } else {
      if (index >= state.posts.length) {
        return const BottomLoader();
      } else {
        return PostListItem(post: state.posts[index]);
      }
    }
  },
  itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.posts.length : state.posts.length + 1,
  controller: _scrollController,
);
```

Comment: I used your approach, but it ends up in blank screen and then Snackbar is displayed later. Is there anyway we can display it over the page which loaded articles?

Comment: Your method is great, but I replaced (return Container();) with (return PostListItem(post: state.posts[index]);)

Answer (score 0):

To display a Snackbar when you reach the end of articles, you can use the `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar()` method.

For Example:

```
// Import the Scaffold and SnackBar classes
import 'package: flutter/material.dart';

// ...

// Inside your build method
if (articles.length == 0) {
  // Display the SnackBar when there are no more articles to read
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text('No more articles to read'),
    ),
  );
}
```

This will display the Snackbar when the articles list is empty. You can customize the Snackbar by setting its content, duration, and other properties.

Comment: Nah, it gets error and says: You need to give a return on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScaffoldMessanger to show snackbr as below,

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (state.hasReachedMax) {
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( <--- here use ScaffoldMessenger instead of Scaffold
     SnackBar(
      content: const Text('Reach the end of posts'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        onPressed: () {
          //if action button is pressed
        },
        label: 'Close',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return SizedBox();
   } else {
     if (index >= state.posts.length) {
       return const BottomLoader();
   } else {
    return PostListItem(post: state.posts[index]);
   }
 }
},
  itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.posts.length : state.posts.length + 1,
  controller: _scrollController,
);
```

Comment: Nah, it gets error and says: You need to give a return on the condition.

Comment: I have edited return SizedBox(), please check